# What is the correct way to return a substring(n, m) within a method statement in Java?

Tags: java, string

I am going through previous exam questions and my question is what is the correct way or ways to determine a String length and return it.

If the String is less than 5 characters in length then I can return it the following way:

```
public static String first5(String s){
     if(s.length() < 5)
     return s;
}
```

If the String is greater than 5 characters though, it can be returned in the following way:

```
public static String first5(String s){

     return s.substring(0, 4);
}
```

What I must note is that when I answered this type of question before in an in class test, my lecturer stressed that I should not really use 'magic numbers'?
I am not sure what he actually meant by that though.

Is there a better way to return this type of method at all?

I am still learning Java so please forgive any errors in my syntax.

Many thanks.

Comment: Combine and put this `return s.length() < 5 ? s : s.substring(0, 4)`. There is no magic number involved because you want first 5 characters.

Comment: Your second implementation will only return 4 characters, not 5...

Comment: Ah, yes I see. It actually stops before the 4th character.

Comment: You don't return a substring, you return a String object which happens to be identical in value to a substring of the input object.

Comment: No its fine. Apologies. Please ignore last comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad

Comment: Thanks Franklin. Thats great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be your method `first5`:

```
public static String first5(String s){
  return s.length() < 5? s : s.substring(0, 5);
}
```

There are no magic numbers here, but maybe the teacher meant the number 5 was a magic number and wanted you to generalize the function:

```
public static String firstN(String s, int n){
  return s.length() < n? s : s.substring(0, n);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks Marko. Can I ask what the ? and s : s.substring is?
Is it like a 'for each' loop so to speak?

Comment: It is the conditional operator: if the expression before `?` is true, the result is the one after `?`; otherwise the result is the one after `:`. It's like `if`, but an expression instead of a statement.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially if the requirements ever change, you can easily change the value in one location; thus, it will be changed everywhere it's referenced. You won't have to worry about any fragments of the old requirements floating around in the code. This is generally a good rule to follow with a large chunk of code.

```
public class solution {
    static final int VAR1 = 0;
    static final int VAR2 = 4;
    static final int VAR3 = 5;
    public static String first5(String s){
        if(s.length() < VAR3) { 
            return s;
        } else {
            return s.substring(VAR1, VAR2);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course the variable names will have to be named something meaningful to the class/application itself.

Comment: That's pointless -- using "FIVE" instead of "5" does not make it less of a "magic number".

Comment: `FOUR` is not needed - see comment above :)

Comment: So according to your edit, `FIVE` could be `4` in the future?

Comment: @KennethK. - Right.  Just change FIVE to be 4 and everything will be OK.  (Or is it the other way around??)

Comment: note edits. used different variable names to lessen confusion

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's no great shame in using an if statement:

```
String r = null;
if (s.length() < 5) {
    r = s;
}
else {
    r = s.substring(0,5);
}
return r;
```

The logic is clearer than if you use `?:`.  The advantage of the latter is that it occupies less screen real-estate, so you can get more of a large function onto a screen -- valuable if you have a large function, but counter-productive if not.

Comment: Ufff, when I see this kind of code in a project, it sets my hair on fire. There are so many things that can go wrong here, there are so many minute details to check to make certain there are no bugs. Especially when you are looking around a 100KLOCS codebase searching for the root cause of a `NullPointerException`. You could have at least made `r` final and not initialized to `null`. That would have helped a lot.

Comment: It uses a variable that it doesn't really need. Two return statements would have served better. We obviously disagree on the effectiveness of the conditional operator, so I'm not going there :)

Comment: Two return statements is an option, but can be dangerous in a larger routine.  (I can recall a case where a return from the middle of a routine led to a "manhunt" involving about 20 programmers and several weeks of schedule.)

Comment: This answer doesn't have much to do with the question of magic numbers.

Comment: @Franklin - The meaning of which, in the context of this question, has never really been defined.

Comment: @Hot Licks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad

Comment: @Franklin - Yet another "rule" that can be carried to ridiculous extremes.  If the name of the method is "first5", there's no real point in parameterizing "5" -- in fact, it could be dangerous.

Comment: Two return statements are no more dangerous than two assignment statements. It is exactly as difficult track them all down---and that's if the variable is final. If not, the problem explodes. Separately, each variable requires you to make another mental slot in your short-term memory that tracks that variable. Three more such in the code, and your STM is overloaded, so now you're scrolling up and down the method trying to juggle all the balls at once, constantly failing at some end.

Comment: Two return statements are MUCH more dangerous than two assignment statements, since, after the return statement, nothing else gets executed.

Comment: The method is either correct or incorrect. Statements not getting executed will just make the incorrectness more visible.

Comment: It's all about visibility.  When you're maintaining a million lines of code, being able to look at it and make sense of it is important, and not having "surprises" is a big part of that.  It is NOT true that something is "either correct or incorrect".  It's possible for something to be correct (or not) and be deceiving, and that's the worst kind of code.  Clarity is ultimately more important than absolute correctness, since an incorrect method can be debugged, but an unclear method cannot.

Comment: Now you have changed the subject and misinterpreted my sentence. You said two returns are dangerous because nothing gets executed after return. That's a comment on the method's **behavior**, which I countered is either correct or incorrect, and something being "more incorrect" may actually be an advantage because the incorrectness is more visible. And well, hardly anything is more deceiving in Java than a hidden reassignment of variables.

Comment: You started all this by criticizing the style of the snippet (which was, if you'll recall, simply offered as an alternative, to be more easily understood).  I have 40 years of programming experience and a modest understanding of what styles are "dangerous".  Well-structured code, even if not perfect, is preferable to code that may be correct now but won't be after the first modification made by someone who could not readily understand it.  (And any piece of "real" code of any substance WILL be modified.)  (And there's nothing wrong with the **behavior** of the code I posted.)

Answer (score 0):

Is the number 5 is in your question? If not get the number as input argument with the string input.